# How to take another UserName?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to ask when I am already logged in with one username how to access the  username of another user?

I have that controller where I add some fields to Users table.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var username = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    return View(username);
}

public ActionResult Edit()
{

    ApplicationUser profile = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    if (profile == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(profile);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id, Nickname, FirstName, LastName, SecondName, City, Address, Description, TelNum")] ApplicationUser profile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = db.Users.Find(profile.Id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        user.UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        user.FirstName = profile.FirstName;
        user.SecondName = profile.SecondName;
        user.LastName = profile.LastName;
        user.Address = profile.Address;
        user.City = profile.City;
        user.TelNum = profile.TelNum;
        user.Description = profile.Description;
        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("/Profile/Index/" + profile.Id);
    }
    return View(profile);
}
```

Here I want when I click on that link

```
<div>
    <a href="Profile/Index/" style="color:black"><b>@item.Author</b></a>
</div>
```

To go to the other user profile.

Comment: `href="Profile/Index/"` is going to redirect to the `Index()` method. You need a method that has a parameter identifying the ID or some other property of the `User` you want to display e.g `Details(int ID)` and call it with `href="Profile/Details/#"` where # identifies the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "access a username".  That's now how it works.

You need to design your application in such a way that you can render a page based on an arbitrary user, making sure that if there is sensitive information that you are not showing or allowing a user to edit information they should not be able to.

This means that you need to provide a way to look up a user based on another factor, such as username or userid.  Typically, this would be passed on the URL, such as http://example.com/profiles/theuser

Then, in your profilescontroller.index method, you get that id, look up the user in the database, and render the page based on that information.  But, this is all stuff you have to write.